# ¿Por qué no se visualiza mi tipografía en los navegadores móviles?

Tags: wordpress, fuentes, google-fonts

En mi proyecto tuve que tengo que usar la tipografía **"Cooper Black"**, ya que esta no existe en google fonts tuve que descargarla manualmente y subirla a la carpeta de mi sitio web.

Cuando visualizo mi sitio web en un laptop o computador de escritorio mi sitio web sí reconocer la tipografía **"Cooper Black"** en todas la páginas, pero cuando la veo desde cualquier teléfono o tableta, en ves de reconocer **Cooper Black** me muestra la **Roboto Slab**.

Revise el CSS y el HTML y agregue correctamente la fuente, aun no comprendo porque no funciona.

Agradecería una respuesta.

Mi css es el siguiente:

```
*{
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cooper';
    src:'cooper-black.ttf';
}
h1{
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--color-primario);
    color: white;
    font-family:'Cooper', 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px !important;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: medium;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    span.black-text{
        color: var(--color-primario);
        font-family: inherit;
        }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar lo que has intentado, mediante un [mcve]. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para agregar lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, ya lo modifique, saludos.

Comment: Por qué no intentas colocarle 1 sólo tipo de fuente a tu <h1>? O establecer una clase específica para los textos que vayan a usar la fuente Cooper?

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis de @font-face es:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:<nombre_de_la_fuente>;
    src: url(<ruta_url>) [format()][,url(<ruta_url>) [format()]]*;
    [font-weight:<weight>];
    [font-style:<estilo>];
    [font-stretch]:<stretch>];
    [unicode-range]:<range>];
}
```

en tú caso sería:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Cooper';
    src:url('cooper-black.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```